# Images not loading HTML

Tags: html, web

I have been through multiple threads but none of then are specific enough,
I have got a very basic website on netlify and my images wont load. They are there as i copy and pasted the url in my code into the browser, I have tried everything I know of Is there anything I can do to fix this?

````
<body id="p">
<img scr="https://colourpicker23.netlify.app/images/image.jpg" alt="image should be here"></img>
<label for="colorWell">Color:</label>
<input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="colorWell">
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1):

You mispelled source "src"

Answer (score 1):

You are using `scr` instead of img `src` property:

```
<img src="https://colourpicker23.netlify.app/images/image.jpg" alt="image should be here"></img>
```

Fixing this line should allow your image to render

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```html
<body id="p">
   <img src="https://colourpicker23.netlify.app/images/image.jpg" alt="image should be here" width="20%"/>
   <label for="colorWell">Color:</label>
   <input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="colorWell">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have "scr" instead of "src" in your img tag. Just use the right spelling and it will works.

Comment: Thanks ill try that, sometimes I amuse my myself how dumb I can get